# calling jquery methods on javascript variables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a js variable and then run a jquery method off that variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".header").length; i++) {
  let header = $(".header").get( i );
  header.text("cool");
}
```

But when I run the method off the variable I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: header.text is not a function
```

I've tried joining the two lines together but that was all I could think of. 
And the js file is definitely connected to the page.
And the header class is from my html file and I've tried some console.log()'s and it's definitely selecting the elements.

I was expecting this code to change two elements with a class of .header in my html to say cool but instead nothing changed at all apart from the error message appearing in my console.

Comment: I don't remember, but I don't think `.get()` returns a jQuery object wrapper. It just returns whatever element is in the `i`th position. So, this should work: `$(header).text("cool")`; or `let header = $($(".header").get( i ));`

Comment: What's the point of looping `$(".header")` when you want to change them all anyway? Just use `$(".header").text("Cool");` without the loop. Otherwise, you could do a `$(".header").each(...)` to change the text one by one, which would be useful if you wanted to use different text per element.

Comment: Hi! your solution worked! I was using the for loop because I was going to take values out of a json file and the headers would be different but thanks! I understand the solution and the problem now!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here in the [documentation for jQuery `.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get-index) method, the `.get()` method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object. And DOM node does not have any `text()` method.

So you just need to wrap `header` again in `$()` to make it a jQuery object:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".header").length; i++) {
  let header = $(".header").get(i);
  $(header).text("cool");
}
```

Though there is a simple way to do what you want:-

```
$(".header").text('cool');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.get(i)` returns the underlying DOM element of the i'th element in the jQuery collection. To get the jQuery object, use `.eq(i)`.

So it should be either:

```
let header = $(".header").eq(i);
```

or

```
header.innerText = "cool";
```